# Caro-Kann Defense: Advance Variation, Botvinnik-Carls Defense

Tags: opening, caro-kann

I seem to keep losing games as white in this opening. What systems is good for white and what are the developing ideas before the middlegame for white after 4. dxc5?

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. e5 c5 4. dxc5
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some games, or at least the openings, to get a better idea why you are losing. It may not be the opening, or it may be that the positions you are getting do not suit your style, or you just lose tactically later. I would also like to see how black is playing it.

Comment: After ...e6, trying to regain the pawn a3 Bxc5 b4 followed by Bb2+Nf3 seems very solid and sensible for White, as Black will probably try to break in the center with f6.
After ...Nc6 Bb5 your goal is to make regaining the pawn as awkward as possible. If Black tries to bring out his bishop out before playing ...e6 by ...Bf5 I recommend playing Ne2 with the idea of harassing the bishop via Ne2-g3+f4-f5. If you want to dodge the theoretical struggles have a look at 4. Ne2 with the same ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I play the Panov attack:

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 cxd5 4. c4 Nf6 5. Nc3 e6 ( 5... Nc6 6. Bg5 e6 7. Nf3 Be7 8. c5 O-O 9. Bb5 Bd7 10. O-O ) 6. Nf3 Be7 7. cxd5 Nxd5 8. Bd3 Nc6 9. O-O O-O 10. Re1
```

I scored multiple victories with this line and it's easy to play. In the first variation, you have an isolated pawn and you're looking for a kingside attack by creating a battery with the Bishop and Queen on the b1-h7 diagonal, and you play a3 in order to prevent the Knight from harassing you light-square bishop and rook on open files. In the second variation (5...Nc6) you need to prevent Black from playing e5. So you need to control it more, or trade your light square bishop for the knight on c6 to control it more and try to create a passed pawn on the queenside by pushing b4 at the right time.